# jQuery selector - All elements except first label and input?

Tags: jquery

I feel like I should be able to use the :not(:first-child) selector here, but it does not seem to work quite as I had hoped.

http://jsfiddle.net/39KZ9/6/

I would like to have the label still appear. How can I achieve that simply?

```
<div id="OrdersSearchResult">
    <input type="radio" id="SearchResultsLink" name="SearchResultNavigation" checked="checked"/>
    <label id="SearchResultsLinkLabel" for="SearchResultsLink">Search Results</label>
</div>​

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#OrdersSearchResult').children('label:not(:first-child)').remove();
    $('#OrdersSearchResult').children('input:not(:first-child)').remove();
});​
```

**Update:** Just so it's clear, I was hopng that the first-child selector would look for the first child of the already matched elements. That is, I want it to select all inputs which are not the first input found and similiarly for labels. Unfortunately, it matches on the first child element of OrdersSearchResult's children regardless of other filters applied.

Comment: So what do you want to remove?

Comment: In the shown example nothing should be removed. I would expect both selectors to not remove anything. Unfortunately, the first-child selector looks at the entire collection of elements and not the already-matched collection of elements.

Comment: It's working as it should - it removes `label` which is `not the first child`

Comment: @wroniasty Correct. I would like to find a selector which cares about first-child for labels and first-child for inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/39KZ9/16/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#OrdersSearchResult').children('label:gt(0)').remove();
    $('#OrdersSearchResult').children('input:gt(0)').remove();
});​
```

Use greater than selector.

`:gt(0)` basically says items greater than the first since an index of `0` is the first.

http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

By the way `:first-child` returns the first child of the parent element not the first in a group of elements.

Even simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#OrdersSearchResult').children('label:gt(0),input:gt(0)').remove();
});​
```

Comment: I think this is the winner. :)

Comment: I think so too. I had actually forgot about `:gt()` and `:lt()`. Super useful.

Answer (score 2):

Do this, for labels and inputs:

```
var labels = $('#OrdersSearchResult > label').toArray();
labels.shift();
$(labels).remove();
```

Or maybe:

```
$($('#OrdersSearchResult > label').toArray().shift()).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have removed the non first-child element already in your fiddle: the label.

I suppose you want to remove the non-first field group which includes both input and it's label. In that case, check out http://jsfiddle.net/39KZ9/8/

Comment: This does what I want, but I was hoping to not have to wrap my contents in a div. I'll accept in a few if there's nothing simpler, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

The selector :first-child let you select the first child of a specific node.

In your code, the first child is the first input. All others nodes are not first child, so, it will be removed by your jQuery calls.

In order to solve your problem, you have to group each couple of input and label in a container `(<p>, <div>, ...)` and apply the jQuery call on these container.